# Unable to get usable data from System.__COMObject

Tags: c#, com, marshalling

I am working with a third party SDK (Proprietary) which I have referenced in my console app, I been tasked to help build a solution which will facilitate many everyday tasks.  However, as I been building one part of the solution I am observing that certain items return objects which to me looks like errors.  This only happens with certain items, however other items return meaningful data, so I assume is related to it being null, or non existent.  However I would like to ask the community for some insight.

**Examples**

When I look in to get a customer's binder GUID (Good Case)

```
string getGuid = currentWorkingPaper.ClientGUID; << I get meaningfull data that I can use
```

On the other hand when I look into accounts of the same customer binder (Bad Case)

```
 var value1 = currentWorkingPaper.RootEntity.Accounts; << returns {System.__ComObject}
```

When I drill down into {System.__ComObject} I get the following

[image]

**My attempts to get data**

I am tried to drill into get into this com object to see if I can get some information with the following actions but I am not getting any data that is usable.

**First Attempt:**

```
var whatIsThis1 = value1.GetType().GetMembers();

**Returns**

 -      whatIsThis1 {System.Reflection.MemberInfo[7]}   System.Reflection.MemberInfo[]
+       [0] {System.String ToString()}  System.Reflection.MemberInfo {System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo}
+       [1] {System.Object GetLifetimeService()}    System.Reflection.MemberInfo {System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo}
+       [2] {System.Object InitializeLifetimeService()} System.Reflection.MemberInfo {System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo}
+       [3] {System.Runtime.Remoting.ObjRef CreateObjRef(System.Type)}  System.Reflection.MemberInfo {System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo}
+       [4] {Boolean Equals(System.Object)} System.Reflection.MemberInfo {System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo}
+       [5] {Int32 GetHashCode()}   System.Reflection.MemberInfo {System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo}
+       [6] {System.Type GetType()} System.Reflection.MemberInfo {System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo}
```

**Second Attempt**

```
var whatIsThis2 = value1.GetType().AssemblyQualifiedName;
**returns**
whatIsThis2 "System.__ComObject, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"   string
```

**Third Attempt**

```
var whatIsThis3 = value1.GetType().GetFields();
**Returns**
whatIsThis3 {System.Reflection.FieldInfo[0]}    System.Reflection.FieldInfo[]
```

**Appendix**

After my third attempt I see that it is returning no fields, so I assume that it may be, that when I get a System.__COMObject it is because I am trying to get data that is null or does not exist.  Because, I only get these object with certain items which I am trying to get. However I am curious to see exactly what is inside of those com object.

Comment: Look at the return type of the method, it is surely *object*.  You can usually cast it to one of the interface types supported by the component.  Then the debugger gets smart again.  Also smells like a collection object that isn't interesting unless you iterate it with foreach.  Actual underlying runtime type is a *proxy*, happens when you call the method from a worker thread or if it is an out-of-process server.  Use a telephone if the manual doesn't help.

Comment: COM objects are objects intended to allow inter process interaction through an interface, you must know which interface it exposes to be able to manipulate it. If you look at the debug, you can see it's an IUnknown, the default interface for COM objects. On that you can use the Marshal functions for COM interop, like QueryInterface https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.queryinterface(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Gusman, yes it makes sense! I will try to cast this object to the interface.  However, I am asked for an interface GUID, this is a bit new to me.  Can you point me to documentation (Examples) please.